# Java Security Error

Tags: java, security, applet, jnlp

When I run my `jnlp` file `WelcomeApplet.jnlp` this security message displays on the screen:

> Application Blocked by Java Security.

I checked on the Internet there are three security levels: **very high, high and medium**. I have `jdk 1.8.0_25` where no `medium` option, just `very high` and `high` are available. What can I do to run this `applet` through web start because on Internet everyone give the solution to check the radio button option of `medium` in Java control panel but there is no such option.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of hoops to jump through to get JWS to work.  For a simple
application, my guess is your application is not signed.  Self-signed certs are no longer acceptable.

Also, on a Mac, the OS has a "run applications from anywhere" option in
the security preferences, which must be checked.

Comment: *"There are lots of hoops to jump through to get JWS to work."* Far fewer than what it takes to get an applet to work reliably.  No.. in fact, scratch the 'work reliably' because Chrome is set to remove support for a number of objects (including applets) that are currently embeddable.

Comment: Then what can i do...I change the security settings from Java Control Panel and also i give path of my file in exception file list but it didn't work....Andrew Thompson i knew about the chrome but what if someone made an applet then what can he do how he checked his applet?